# Multiple domains, one config, hosted on apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

First a quick disclaimer, I'm not a 'server guy' or a 'unix pro' or anything like that, I'm a web programmer who got stuck doing server works since I ran linux (ubuntu) on my netbook.

I'm trying to set up an apache server running on Debian to automagically serve multiple domains, each domain needs to have its own directory in /var/www.

Since this is the last thing I do for this company I really need it to be easy for my successor (who is even more a beginner at servers than I am), to create more domains without having to muck around with ssh or /etc/apache2/sites-available, so what I'm looking for is basically any magic mumbo-jumbo in default (or apt-get, or conf.d) that makes the server start serving any domain that has a matching folder in /var/www they will ofcourse have to initiate domain transfers the usual way.

I have no problem setting up domains individually.

Ick... hope the above makes sense to someone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should take a look at the document on [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).  The article describes a couple different methods you can use to accomplish this.